# Google AMP Adwords conversion tracking

Tags: amp-html, google-ads-api

In an AMP page I want to report a conversion to Adwords when user clicks a certain HTML tag.
How do I config an "amp-analytics" tag to report a conversion to Adwords?

[This](https://developers.google.com/adwords/amp/landing-pages#conversion_tracking_and_remarketing) indicates "amp-analytics" supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I added:
(replace {{googleConversionId}} and {{googleConversionLabel}} below with data from the adwords pixel snippet)

I made sure the my relevant "a" tags had a "clickout" class

```
<amp-analytics type="googleadwords"><script type="application/json">
{
  "triggers": {
    "onClick": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": ".clickout",
      "request": "conversion"
    }
  },
  "vars": {
    "googleConversionId": {{googleConversionId}},
    "googleConversionLanguage": "en",
    "googleConversionFormat": "3",
    "googleConversionLabel":{{googleConversionLabel}}",
    "googleRemarketingOnly": "false"
  }
}
```

It works, I see conversions  in adwords dashboard